# Can you run a GUI on a google app engine Debian 7 server?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, gui, google-app-engine

I've set up a vm server with google app engine. The machine type is n1-standard-1([more info](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types)) and the OS is Debian 7. What I want to do is have some kind of GUI. Is it possible? How can you do it?

I tried installing LXDE but when I type "startx" I get a "Fatal server error: no screens foud(EE)". I then figured I should check the video stuff so I downloaded some utils to get lspci. When I run lspci, I get the following output:

```
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 03)
00:01.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 03)
00:03.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Red Hat, Inc Virtio SCSI
00:04.0 Ethernet controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio network device
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this; I guess there is no video controller? Could I still run LXDE or another GUI?

Comment: have you installed the guest tools for your virtualization platform? usually they include video device drivers. you can certainly install a gui on a Debian server, though the process will be affected by your exact distro and hardware. your error message is indicating that your xorg,conf is not correctly set up, but you are right, you need to see a video device in order to install/configure a driver for it, and define your xorg. man, that brings back nightmares of 2006. xorg used to be the gauntlet that tested the hearts and minds of linux adherents.